# Why are there more trapped protons during solar minima?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, plasma-physics, cosmic-rays

Reading about trapped protons and eletrons in van Allen belts, I get the understanding that the number of trapped electrons increase during a solar maximum (which I find logical because we have more solar flares etc.), but that the number of trapped protons increase during a solar **min**imum. What is the explanation?

Also: what is "atmospheric cut-off"?

Answer (score 1):

Without the influence of an external force, the protons will happily gyrate around the magnetic field while bouncing from pole-to-pole as they drift around the Earth in the [radiation belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt).  During a [geomagnetic storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm), the Earth's field changes rapidly causing protons in the radiation belts to either precipitate into the atmosphere or hit the [magnetopause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere).  In both cases, they are generally considered lost and no longer trapped.

Geomagnetic storms are caused by solar eruptions called [coronal mass ejections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) or CMEs (and high speed streams).  CMEs are produced by enhanced magnetic activity on the sun, which occurs more frequently during solar maximum.